# Build failure for react-native-reanimated

Tags: react-native

I am currently using MacBook Air M1 2020 w/ OS 11.6, and I have been encountering an issue with running the simulator after installing react-native-reanimated. Any other installations (e.g. `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` and `@react-navigation/stack`) work fine, but when I try run (`react-native run-ios`) after installing `react-native-reanimated`, it gives the following error message:

> ----
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:
> CompileC /Users/**USERNAME**/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-bsbiygstdsripxdqednowpxwwzst/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNReanimated.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UIResponder+Reanimated.o /Users/**USERNAME**/Documents/GitHub/ReactNative-Projects/App/node_modules/react-native-reanimated/ios/native/UIResponder+Reanimated.mm normal arm64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNReanimated' from project 'Pods')
>
> ---

When I first install the package via `npm install react-native-reanimated`, it throws a vulnerability issue saying there are
65 vulnerabilities (10 moderate, 30 high, 25 critical),
but there, it doesn't cause any issue during `pod install` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update `react-native-reanimated` to `2.3.0-beta.2` or higher.

Comment: The difference of upgrading from beta.1 to beta.2 is what fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: How did you update reanimated? I tried "npm install react-native-reanimated@next" but it got updated to 2.3.0-beta.1 and is giving me the same error.

Comment: Resolved! used cleared cache and used "npm install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-beta.2". Thank you so much!

Comment: @LeetCodeYeet you can also do `npm update react-native-reanimated`. I just did that myself.

Answer (score 0):

`platform :iOS '13.4'` in `Podfile` fixed for me.